# Android AutoCompleteTextView with '@' mentions filtering like twitter and facebook

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, multiautocompletetextview, tokenautocomplete

I have a requirement for implementing an edit text that the user can type in a anything but when they type in a new word that starts with '@' the autocomplete should start showing potential users.

I understand how to use the AutoCompleteTextView function for filtering. But I am not sure how to go about capturing the characters from the last word after the '@' symbol (ignoring any previous words).

Consequently when the user has been selected from the AutoCompleteTextView list, it should replace the the word with '@', eg.

---

*"This is a message for @steve"*

---

when the user clicks on "Steve" from the list, the text should replace to:

---

*"This is a message for **Steve**"*

---

I also need to obtain the string in a form that I can send off to the server. i.e. from the above example I would need to send off the string:

---

*"This is a message for [username:steve@bloggs.com, id:44]."*

---

I have looked at https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Which seems great for typing emails in a list, but I am not sure how to cater it for my needs. Bare in mind, I need to support multiple/duplicate mentions:

eg

---

*"This is a message for **Steve** and **Bob**. this is the second sentence in the message for **Bob**"*

---

If anyone knows or has done anything like this, would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the spyglass library from linkedin which does exactly what I was looking for. It provides a MentionsEditText (that can be customised). I also used a ListPopupWindow to show the suggestions in a list (like an AutoCompleteTextView).

Here is the link...

https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass

Comment: how you obtain a string with this format? : "This is a message for [username:steve@bloggs.com, id:44]."

Comment: @FlashAsh99 Could you please tell how you did replacing of the text after using spyglass

Comment: @FlashAsh99 I too want to know how did you replace the text with spyglass

Comment: @FlashAsh99: Right now, the code in git currently gets the user/city date from raw file. Is there any way to load dynamic array for this ?

Comment: Answer to @AnaLlera?

Comment: I have also used the same lib. But in my case edit text is at the bottom. The pop up window covers up the keyboard

Answer (score 4):

The following method will extract words starting with "@":

```
private void parseText(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split("[ \\.]");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() > 0
                && words[i].charAt(0) == '@') {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the words, use your auto complete filter and finally replace text using String.replace.